# NodeJS + Express slowly consuming more and more CPU

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, azure-application-insights

We have a strange issue where we have an endpoint in NodeJS+Express, this endpoint is called once every x minutes.
And each time it has been called, we see in our logs (Application insights in Azure to be specific) that the CPU usage have increased slightly.

Over time, CPU usage will end up at 100% and become unresponsive.

What I find strange is that we really do not do anything funky in this endpoint.

We fetch a lot of mongodb documents, iterate over them, do some processing, saving back a few. and that's it.

Are there any known pitfalls where CPU might leak using any of the above tools/frameworks ?

I'm thinking if we have configured something wrong that makes requests linger on forever somehow.

I cannot specify much more as I don't have a clue what could be the origin of this.

Comment: What's the memory usage like? Use a debugger to step through the route... after the function ends where does it go?

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?? Much like submitting a bug report, such statements as *"This happens when I run my application"* simply has no context and is essentially an unfounded statement without showing the necessary steps in order to "reproduce" the issue. You can attempt to do that or look for things like tailable cursors and such which might be sources of consuming CPU. But generally without an MCVE, this is not really something someone here can help you with.

Comment: @Roger Johansson We are facing a similar issue. What was the fix for you guys?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the job is not completing before the next job? I can't tell from your explanation.

**I have a couple of suggestions though:**

Time the requests, if it is consistently failing around x minutes, then set that as the timeout, at least so that it won't kill other processes, or put this job on a separate thread.

1. Maybe go to a batch system (have a flag on the documents, query if it exists or false and set a $limit the result set, then set the flag accordingly once that document has been processed)
2. What does your memory look like? Are you able to use projections to limit the data processed on the back-end.
3. If you are only updating a few documents, maybe you should re-visit the query. I would rather filter the result-set with the query, then bringing in a bunch of documents irrelevant to filter with JS.
4. Memory management in the code - unfetch the queries, set the arrays to null once your done using them, etc.

Comment: @roger - Did you get to check out my suggestions?